# Dynamically change the size of embeded flash file in html object using javascript based on viewing area

Tags: javascript, html, flash, resize

I have a page with a small one line header and a video on it.  I need the video to not be so large that it goes "over-the-fold".
I'm embedding the Flash video into a webpage using the following embed-code:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="AdobeCaptions_controller.swf" width="800" height="722">
<param name="quality" value="best" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="#1a1a1a" />
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
<param name="scale" value="showall" />
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
<param name="flashvars" value="autostart=false&thumb=FirstFrame.png&thumbscale=45&color=0x1A1A1A,0x1A1A1A" />
```

Unfortunately some of my coworkers are a bit on the elderly side and have zoomed their browsers in to ridiculously small sizes.  I know how to use javascript to determine the viewing area of their browser, but I can't seem to control the width and height values in the html with this.  I'm sure I'm missing one of the simplest details.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's weird the code didn't post.

Comment: `<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="AdobeCaptions_controller.swf" width="800" height="722">
                    <param name="quality" value="best" />
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#1a1a1a" />
                    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
                    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
                    <param name="flashvars" value="autostart=false&thumb=FirstFrame.png&thumbscale=45&color=0x1A1A1A,0x1A1A1A" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

I figured out what I was doing wrong.  For anyone who stumbles across this post in the future, I found that you can't dynamically resize flash content without re-embedding a new object.  I was able to obtain a satisfactory result with the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var vid_width = 800;
var vid_height = 722;
if (window.innerWidth){ //if browser supports window.innerWidth
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
}
else if (document.all){ //else if browser supports document.all (IE 4+)
    var width = document.body.clientWidth;
    var height = document.body.clientHeight;
}
if(height<(vid_height+40)){//if window is not tall enough
    var scale_factorH = (height-40)/vid_height;
    vid_height = vid_height * scale_factorH;
    vid_width = vid_width * scale_factorH;
}
if(width<vid_width){//if window is not wide enough
    var scale_factorW = width/vid_width;
    vid_height = vid_height * scale_factorW;
    vid_width = vid_width * scale_factorW;
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("<object ");
document.write(" width = '"+vid_width+"' ");
document.write(" height = '"+vid_height+"' ");
document.write("id='csSWF'>");
</script>
```